# Import CSV File to a new Excel Worksheet within an existing Excel Workbook

Tags: powershell

I'm Trying to import 2 different CSV files into an excel workbook on 2 different worksheets.

I've figured out how to create an excel workbook and import one of the CSV files. But when creating a new worksheet, I can't seem to import the 2nd CSV file into the new worksheet the same way that I imported the first CSV file.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Excel = $Excel.Workbooks.open(C:\Temp\CSVfile1.csv)

#Create new worksheet and import 2nd CSV file
$Excel.Worksheets.add()
$Excel.Sheets(1).Name = 'Errors'
$Excel2 = $Excel.Workbooks.open(C:\Temp\CSVfile2.csv)
```

The first CSV file import is successful. The 2nd worksheet is created, but the 2nd csv file is not imported.

Error message displayed is

`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend using the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module for any Excel-related files, it makes them much easier to work with and only takes a couple seconds to get it working. Moreover it has the benefit of using reading and editing Excel files without needing Microsoft Excel to be installed.

See the following example to do what you're looking for using the ImportExcel module:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\CSVfile1.csv' | Export-Excel -Path 'C:\Temp\ExportExcelTest.xlsx' -WorkSheetname 'Sheet1'
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\CSVfile2.csv' | Export-Excel -Path 'C:\Temp\ExportExcelTest.xlsx' -WorkSheetname 'Errors'
```

Additionally, ImportExcel also comes along with many formatting options which may be of use to you. I can't recommend it enough over using a ComObject to modify an Excel file.

Comment: [Here is a link to the PowerShell Gallery site](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) for the module. It really is very well done.

Comment: @Floogen Thanks for the information on the module, but i'm trying to do this without any exterior modules. The goal is for any admin in my environment to be able to run the script using only default powershell resources. Also sorry for the delayed response, I just returned from an extended LOA.